# Expand a MongoDB record with a new field

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to expand a MongoDB row with a new column/field with a new column named `key_reference`, which doesn't seem to work. This is my Query in Robo 3T (similar to MySQL Workbench for MySQL or PgAdmin for Postgres)

```
doc1=db.getCollection('store.files').find({ _id : ObjectId("5ad5a07ccbce1d0873264ee6")});

doc1({$addFileds:{'key_reference':'1234'}});
```

What do I miss?

Comment: You have to use update query for it `db.getCollection('store.files').findOneAndUpdate({ _id : ObjectId("5ad5a07ccbce1d0873264ee6")},{$set:{key_reference:'12345'}});
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) is an **Aggregation Pipeline Stage** which means that it can be used only with `.aggregate()` method, try:

```
db.getCollection('store.files').aggregate([
    { $match: { _id : ObjectId("5ad5a07ccbce1d0873264ee6")} },
    { $addFields:{'key_reference':'1234'}}
]);
```

Comment: there’s a typo in ur code it should be `$addFields` not `$addFileds`

Comment: @ShivamSood thank you !